# How to install extensions not included on PHP 5.6? GDlib, DOM, MCrypt

Tags: php, dom, wamp, mcrypt

I've recently installed PHP, Apache and MySQL on a windows server 2012. I have everything working and I already have a website up and running on the server.

In the next few weeks I will be transferring a new site on this server however this new sites requires extensions not currently installed on PHP 5.6, they are as follows:

- GDlib
- DOM
- MCrypt

How do I go about installing these extensions on PHP?

This was my first time installing a WAMP server, still trying to figure things out

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Have you checked each extension's documentation? They might be able to tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what version of PHP you are moving from but if you check the changelogs for PHP I think you will find that `mcrypt` and `DOM` are part of the PHP Core now and GD1 has been replaced wih GD2 which should also be active by default in WAMPServer

If it is not then it can be turned on using the wampmanager menus

```
wampmanager -> PHP -> Extensions -> php_gd2
```

Comment: I didn't use an all in one ready to go WAMP server so no menu to select extensions for me. I Installed each bit separately and joined them together. However as you mentioned on `mcrypt` and `DOM` came pre installed. I came from php 5.2

Comment: I will remove the wampserver tag for you then

Answer (score 0):

Most of the extensions will be available with the WAMP server

To enable an extension click on the wamp tray icon on the task bar goto `PHP->PHP extensions->` Click on the extension you want to enable.

If you don't find the extension you are looking for then you may have to install it manually.Download the extension dll file and place it inside PHP extension folder(`wamp\bin\php\php5.*\ext`) and include the dll name in php.ini and restart.

Comment: Most extensions are on there ready to be installed, however on earlier version of PHP the DOM and mcrypt had to be downloaded and installed separately. Fortunately as it turns out on 5.6 they come ready, pre-installed without having to do anything.